# Сервисы по типу firebase

Tags: android, база-данных, хранилище

Здравствуйте, какие сервисы лучше всего выбрать как замену Firebase? От последнего пришлось отказаться в связи с тем, что затруднен доступ к БД и данным с ПК.

Интересует возможность создания своих БД, бесплатное хранилище файлов ~5 Гб, доступ к ним как из программ, написанных на С++ на ПК, так и из программ на android. Спасибо

Answer (score 1):

Я бы на вашем месте взял недорогую VPS, поставил бы туда node.js + socket-io + zeromq + postgresql, и можно делать всё что заблагорассудится - чаты или другие динамические приложения.

VPS конечно не бесплатная, но у вас за $10 в месяц будет полная свобода действий зато.

Через zeromq будет удобнее работать с C++ приложениями, хотя в принципе можно и без нее.

В PostgreSQL прекрасные возможности для хранения и обработки JSON-данных, многими годами проверенная надежность и производительность.